# Homology of $S^1\times \mathbb{RP}^2$ without using Kunneth's Theorem

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

I am trying to compute the homology of $S^1\times \mathbb{RP}^2$ for all $n\geq 0$. I read online that Kunneth's Theorem about homology of product spaces might be useful, but unfortunately, we haven't covered that in my course, so I think I should not use it. I tried to picture the space as follows

[image]

I want to use a CW complex structure to compute the homology. My idea is to assign a single 0-cell to a point in the exterior of the solid "torus", then two 1-cells, each a loop of the torus (meridian and longitude), then one 2-cell representing the surface of the torus, and finally a 3-cell representing the "filling" of the torus. However, I have been having trouble computing the degrees of the attaching maps composed with the projections. For example, I want to compute

$\partial_2:\mathbb{Z}e_1^2 \to \mathbb{Z}e^1_1 \oplus \mathbb{Z}e^1_2$

where I know that

$\partial_2(e^2_1) = $deg$(p_1\circ \phi)e_1^1 + $deg$(p_2\circ \phi)e^1_2$

where $e^k_i$ represents the ith k-cell and $p_i: X = S^1\times \mathbb{RP}^2 \to X/(X- e^1_i)$. Also $\phi:S^1\to X$ is the attaching map. I believe in this case deg$(p_1\circ \phi)=2$ because of the $\mathbb{RP}^2$ condition on the boundary, and deg$(p_2\circ \phi)=1$ since it is basically the identity. This would give me (I believe) that $H_1(X) = \mathbb{Z}/2$. However, I am not sure about this, and I don't know how to procede with computing $\partial_3:\mathbb{Z}e^3_1\to \mathbb{Z}e^2_1$, so in $\partial_3 = $deg$(p_1\circ \phi)e^2_1$, I can't figure out what the degree is supposed to be.

I would appreciate it if someone could guide me on this path or tell me if this is a wrong way of thinking about this problem. Thank you.

Comment: If I take the “obvious” cell structure for the product, I get one $0$-cell, two $1$-cells, two $2$-cells, and one $3$-cell. By the way, isn’t Mayer-Vietoris straightforward?

Comment: Maybe, I haven't tried using Mayer Vietoris since the chapter this problem was assigned on was about CW complexes. I will try using Mayer Vietoris. Just curious, why do you have two 2-cells on your structure? What would they be?

Comment: One $2$-cell is the product of the $1$-cells of $S^1$ and $\mathbb{RP}^2$, the other is the (product of the $0$-cell of $S^1$ with  the) $2$-cell of $\mathbb{RP}^2$.

Comment: I see, one is the "boundary" of the "torus" and the other one is a "cross section". I will try using these as well. If using Mayer Vietoris, I think the choices of open sets would be the two halves of the "torus" (like cutting a bagel in half), but I can't picture what these spaces are homeomorhpic to. Are they normal solid toruses? And their intersection too?

Comment: Cut $S^1$ into two (overlapping) pieces.

Comment: I have obtained that $H_0(X) = \mathbb{Z}, H_1(X) = \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2, H_2(X) = \mathbb{Z}/2$ and 0 for all other $n>2$. Does this seem plausible? It seems weird that $H_2$ is not trivial, since it seems like there are no voids in the space.